# QGIS Parallel Line spacing of different layers

Tags: qgis

I am trying to draw parallel lines at a set spacing (say 50 ft apart) for multiple layers at a time. Is there a quick way to draw multiple lines in one go? example of what I would like to create below. Had to try and do it manually, which I would like to avoid.

[image]

Comment: is this for visual effect only or would you like to have spatial data to do analysis or other things on?

Comment: Spatial data preferably. Although both could be potentially helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you have already a layer with lines, you could try a tool from the processing tool box. (I've got a german QGIS, so I don't really now the english name for it, sorry. Search for 'parallel'.) In the screenshot the tool generated the red lines in a temporary layer. Paramter for the new line(s) was '1' in distance 10 Meters. In the result you have the orignal line plus one extra on the northern (left) side of it. If you choose a negative value, the line(s) are created at the opposite side.

[image]

If you have the data already in postgis or spatialite or would like to have something dynamic, you can work with [ST_OffsetCurve](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OffsetCurve.html). E.g. if you want a separate line on the lefthand and seperate one on the righthand, I would create two extra geometry columns in the database to store them. Then update all with a statement. For a dynamic solution -means create the parallel lines at once when a new line is created- you could add triggers which do this automatically.

Comment: it's called __Array of offset (parallel) Lines__

Comment: Also supports batch proccesing, to create both sides for all the layers in one go.